# In graph theory, does the open neighborhood of a set include elements in the set if they are each other's neighbors?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

If so, is it possible for the closed neighborhood and open neighborhoods of a connected graph to be identical?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(graph_theory)) on neighborhoods in graph theory, the open neighborhood of a vertex $v$ is basically defined to be the closed neighborhood of $v$ with the vertex $v$ removed. So no, the open neighborhoods and closed neighborhoods will never be identical.